# How to calculate opacity from transparency?

Tags: c++, rgb, rgba

We are calculating the opacity using the following formula

```
float alpha = 1 - transparency ; // transparency is a float value .
```

Now the user will be supplying transparency in int format ...
What changes should I make to get the opacity ?

Comment: ... multiply by 255? Did you give this any thought at all?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the range of possible alpha values in the floating point format. Assuming the range of possible floating point alpha values is between 0.0 and 1.0 (inclusive), then this will work:

```
#include <cmath>

long lalpha{std::lround(alpha * 255)};
```

In case the upper bound on the floating point alpha range is not equal to 1.0, you can divide the floating point alpha value by the upper bound to normalize to a range from 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive.

Comment: Is opacity and transparency same ? In the existing code I see we are doing 
double alpha = 1- transparency;

Comment: Opacity is the opposite of transparency. An object that is fully opaque is not transparent, and vice versa.

Comment: Ok ..so I have to calulate opacity from transparency ..will ur formula hold good then ?

Comment: No, it is a completely different question.